# cloud_name in tag or in configuration, how can I override this ?

Tags: cloudinary

I'm currently working on a project for a company. When i cloned the code and trying to launch the server, I have this error

```
Must supply cloud_name in tag or in configuration
```

Anyone have a solution to override this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Cloudinary error "Must supply cloud_name in tag or in configuration" message usually means that the Cloudinary library doesn't have your account properly configured, so it doesn't know which Cloudinary account to work with.

You can either set the cloud name directly in your methods, like this (for example in Ruby):

```
<%= cl_image_path("myImage.jpg", :cloud_name => cloudname)%>
```

Alternatively, you can globally configure your account, as explained [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#configuration) (for Rails, you can find your preferred SDK documentation).